# Какие условия должны быть соблюдены для @Inject?

Tags: java, java-ee, servlet, dependency-injection

Предположим есть interface:

```
public interface BookDAO {
    public Book getBookByID(int id);
}
```

Класс:

```
public class BookDAOImpl implements BookDAO {
    public Book getBookByID(int id) {
        .....dowork
  }
}
```

И сервлет:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

@WebServlet("/management")
public class BookStore extends HttpServlet {

   @Inject
   private BookDAO bookDAO;

   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
       List<Book> books = new List<>();
       books = bookDAO.getALLBooks();
   }
}
```

Содержание `src\META-INF\bean.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>
```

Получаю `NullPointerException` на `books = bookDAO.getALLBooks()`, сам же метод в обычном консольном виде через `new BookDAOImpl` отрабатывает нормально.

В Spring пользовался `@Repository` и `@Autowired` + нужно было указать где сканировать, а как дело обстоит через `@Inject`?

Спасибо!

Comment: Аннотируйте `BookDAOImpl`, к примеру, `@Named`, `@Stateless` или каким-либо `@...Scoped`.

Comment: Попробовал в различных вариациях - ничего не поменялось, может быть кроме аннотаций еще что-то я упустил?

Comment: `beans.xml` с минимальным содержимым создан?

Comment: Обновил вопрос, добавил информацию по `bean.xml`.

Comment: `beans.xml` должен лежать в `src/webapp/WEB-INF`.

Comment: Попробовал, плюс покидал в верхние уровни, плюс опять же повторил итерации с `import javax.inject.Named; import javax.ejb.Stateless; import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped`  Импорты правильные?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Конфиг должен называться beans.xml (у вас s на конце пропущена)
2. @Stateless аннотация не нужна, это для EJB, для CDI надо одну из @...Scoped аннотаций

Comment: Ввожу Вас в заблуждение опечаткой, к моему сожалению название файла `beans.xml`. Метод `getALLBooks()` идет к базе через `Connection, ResultSet, PreparedStatement`, а к ним `@Inject` не применяют?

Comment: Вы какой контейнер используете? WildFly, Glassfish? В простом Tomcat CDI без дополнительных библиотек не будет работать

Comment: Ок, еще раз: beans.xml в META-INF

Comment: Ок, еще раз проверьте: 1) beans.xml в META-INF; 2)@ApplicationScoped на BookDAOImpl, import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped; В самом DAO по идее ничего инжектить не нужно, у вас там чистый JDBC, судя по всему.
Да, и в сервлете у вас List<Book> books = new List<>();
Это вообще компилируется?

Comment: List просто для примера вставлен, сами метотды через new отрабатывают и работают с базой. При @Inject создания экземпляра класса не происходит. У меня сейчас Tomcat, какие библиотеки нужно подключить?

Comment: Только для CDI - например, [Weld](http://weld.cdi-spec.org/). Или же есть вариант Tomcat с уже подключенными JavaEE библиотеками - [TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/apache-tomee.html)

Comment: Добавил в `pom.xml` указанный Вами **Weld** - заработало! =) Итого: структура папок стандартная для "`maven archetype webapp`", лишь добавлена папка в `src/META-INF/` и в нем стандартный файл `beans.xml`. Огромное спасибо за помощь и за Ваше потраченное время =)